# Screwturn Move Page(s) to a new namespace

Tags: namespaces, wiki, move, screwturn

G'day

We have been using ScrewTurn wiki for a while now but until now didn't look at the namespaces feature. We would like to move and secure some of our article to a separate namespace however I can not see an easy way to do this from the GUI. From what I can see in the DB structure a number of tables have a Namespace column Pages, Categories, CategoryBinding to name a few but I don't know if it will be ok to just update these.

I was wondering if anyone had any experience or advice on moving pages between namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your new namespace(s) are created first, before continuing.

To move pages one at a time:

- Go to Administration.
- Select 'Wiki Pages'.
- Select the source namespace from the 'Namespace' drop-down at the top.
- Find the page to move and click the 'Select' hyperlink.
- Use the 'Migrate Page' box to move the page to a different namespace.  Select 'Copy Page Categories' to copy any categories to the new namespace.

To move multiple pages at one time:

- Go to Administration.
- Select 'Wiki Pages'.
- Select the source namespace from the 'Namespace' drop-down at the top.
- Click the 'Bulk Migrate' button.
- Use 'Search' to find pages to move.  This will only search the namespace you specified on the 'Wiki Pages' page.
- Select each page to move in the drop-down and click 'Add'.
- Select 'Copy Page Categories' to copy any categories to the new namespace.
- Select Target Namespace and then 'Migrate'.

NOTE: Moving pages to a new namespace may break any existing links to the page from other pages.

BTW, this is using the current version of Screwturn (3.0.5.600).  Older versions may differ slightly but I believe the functionality has been there for a while.

Comment: Thanks for That Doug, I only just saw the response and it worked a treat.

Comment: Hey Doug -- do you want to join the STW project? We could use some contents and docs like this from users. http://stw.codeplex.com